# JPA Query clause Where

Tags: java, jpa

How should to be a query like this in JPA

```
"SELECT t FROM persona t WHERE t.value1 = :value1 AND t.value2 = :value2"
```

I have EntintyManager already defined:

```
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persona"); 
EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
```

wanted return 1 object type Persona same class that I using to mapping

**How should be?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TypedQuery<Persona> q = em.createQuery("SELECT t FROM persona t WHERE t.value1 = :value1 AND t.value2 = :value2", Persona.class);
Persona result = q.setParameter("value1", val1)
                  .setParameter("value2", val2)
                  .setMaxResults(1)
                  .getSingleResult();
```